# What is the smartest way to copy a Map in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I'd like to get a new instance of some Map with the same content but Map doesn't have a built-in `copy` method. I can do something like this:

```
val newInst = someMap.map { it.toPair() }.toMap()
```

But it looks rather ugly. Is there any more smarter way to do this?

Comment: that is very inefficient, lots of temporary objects allocated

Comment: @voddan I know, that's why I've asked this question.

Comment: i think that's a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11221

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Just use the `HashMap` constructor:

```
val original = hashMapOf(1 to "x")
val copy = HashMap(original)
```

---

**Update for Kotlin 1.1:**

[Since Kotlin 1.1](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html), the extension functions `Map.toMap` and `Map.toMutableMap` create copies.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't work for immutable maps, but is still great for mutable ones.

Comment: If you want the result to be of read-only type, declare the type manually or use a cast: `val copy : Map<Int,String> = HashMap(original)` or `val copy = HashMap(original) as Map<Int, String>`. If you do this repeatedly, write an extension function.

Comment: @N.Kudriavtsev maps are not immutable, they are just accessed from a readonly interface.  So the example above does work if you hold it with a readonly variable in the end.

Comment: Butt his solution not working for map of maps.

Answer (score 9):

Use `putAll` method:

```
val map = mapOf("1" to 1, "2" to 2)
val copy = hashMapOf<String, Int>()
copy.putAll(map)
```

Or:

```
val map = mapOf("1" to 1, "2" to 2)
val copy = map + mapOf<String, Int>() // preset
```

Your way also looks idiomatic to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Obviously, you'd like to say `val copy = hashMapOf<String, Int>(); copy.putAll(map)` because putAll returns Unit. Of course it looks better than my code, however, it is a Java method, takes more than one line and doesn't work with immutable maps.. Is it really the best way?

Comment: I've corrected the example. I don't see an problem with calling a Java method, but immutability is important for your case, then your method looks better.

Comment: Calling a Java method is not a problem itself, the problem is when the primitive operation requires more than one line of code in a language that was positioned as a simple alternative for Scala. Your second variant is much better. And I think for now it is the best variant for immutables, so thank you once again! Immutability is not important for me right now, I was just interested.

Comment: Upvoted for the `+` (plus)

Answer (score 2):

The proposed way of doing this is:

```
map.toList().toMap()
```

However, the java's method is 2 to 3 times faster:

```
(map as LinkedHashMap).clone()
```

Anyway, if it bothers you that there is no unified way of cloning Kotlin's collections (and there is in Java!), vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11221

Answer (score 1):

Add this extension (to convert entries to pairs)

```
val <K, V> Map<K, V>.pairs: Array<Pair<K, V>>
    get() = entries.map { it.toPair() }.toTypedArray()
```

And then you can easy combine immutable maps using default Kotlin syntax.

```
val map1 = mapOf("first" to 1)
val map2 = mapOf("second" to 2)
val map3 = mapOf(
    *map1.pairs,
    "third" to 3,
    *map2.pairs,
)
```

Comment: What what what? This looks amazing. Can you please explain the extension and the usage?